# How to generate help/usage description from getopt?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Is there a way to generate the "help" or "usage" message of a command from `getopt`?

Something like this:

```
ARGUMENTS=$(getopt ... -- "$@")
echo $(help "$ARGUMENTS")
```

Output in this format:

```
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --all                  do not ignore entries starting with .
  -A, --almost-all           do not list implied . and ..
      --author               with -l, print the author of each file
  -b, --escape               print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters
      --block-size=SIZE      with -l, scale sizes by SIZE when printing them;
```

Comment: Did you find a native approach to this issue? If not, here's a couple of external generators: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76889923/16780116

Comment: Found another approach, it might be doable with loops: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672214/16780116